# Android: GridLayout size and View.GONE behaviour

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

I want to make a `GridLayout` that when one of it's children's `Visibility` is set to `GONE`, it is replaced by the next child.
[image]

Using `GridLayout`, setting any child's visibility to `View.Gone` simply hides the view.
How can I make it so it behaves like the image above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution would be to use RecyclerView along with GridLayoutManager. The key is to notify adapter about the changes to deleted items by using notifyItemRemoved. There is lots of room for customization in RecyclerViews, such as nice animations for disappearing items, rearrangement of remaining items on the screen, item decorations and etc. You can apply all these customization and additional logic around deletion of the items as needed for your particular problem.

Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        List<String> dataSet = getSampleDataSet();
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.grid);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(dataSet));
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), 2));
    }

    private List<String> getSampleDataSet() {
        List strings = new ArrayList();
        strings.add("one");
        strings.add("two");
        strings.add("three");
        strings.add("four");
        strings.add("five");
        strings.add("six");

        return strings;
    }
}
```

Adapter

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder> {
    List<String> dataSet;



    public MyAdapter(List<String> dataSet) {
        this.dataSet = dataSet;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        TextView tileView = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.grid_item, parent, false);
        MyViewHolder myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(tileView);

        return myViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.view.setText(dataSet.get(position));

        holder.view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                dataSet.remove(position);
                notifyItemRemoved(position); // this notifies the adapter about item being removed
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataSet.size();
    }
}


class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView view;

    public MyViewHolder(TextView itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        view = itemView;
    }
}
```

Activity Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/grid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Grid Item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridItem"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Tile"/>
```

Results
Before:
[image: Before]

After click on 4. On an actual device, you will be able to see a nice framework animation for this action.

[image: After]

Answer (score 7):

Solve same problem as:

```
package ua.vsgroup.widgets;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

public class vsGridLayout extends GridLayout {

    View[] mChild = null;

    public vsGridLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public vsGridLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public vsGridLayout(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    private void arrangeElements() {

        mChild = new View[getChildCount()];
        for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
            mChild[i] = getChildAt(i);
        }

        removeAllViews();
        for (int i = 0; i < mChild.length; i++) {
            if (mChild[i].getVisibility() != GONE)
                addView(mChild[i]);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < mChild.length; i++) {
            if (mChild[i].getVisibility() == GONE)
                addView(mChild[i]);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {

        arrangeElements();
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);

    }


}
```

Comment: This works but is extremely buggy and changes the default view order. Make your improvements before using.

Comment: Here is what I did for my project, https://stackoverflow.com/a/65402196/4437468

Comment: @UtsavBarnwal How to reproduce the bug? I tried the solution, and it works 15 from 15 times in a row?

Answer (score 6):

If you don't need turn the view visible again you can solve it removing the view from GridLayout.

```
private void hideView(View view) {
    GridLayout gridLayout = (GridLayout) view.getParent();
    for (int i = 0; i <  gridLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
        if (view == gridLayout.getChildAt(i)) {
            gridLayout.removeViewAt(i);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39993365/4437468) answer. Thanks man.

Create your custom GridLayout widget.

```
package com.isolpro.pricelist.custom;    

public class RearrangingGridLayout extends GridLayout {
  private final List<View> views = new ArrayList<>();

  public RearrangingGridLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
  }

  public RearrangingGridLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
  }

  public RearrangingGridLayout(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
  }

  private void arrangeElements() {
    removeAllViews();

    for (int i = 0; i < views.size(); i++) {
      if (views.get(i).getVisibility() != GONE)
        addView(views.get(i));
    }
  }

  public void saveViews() {
    for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
      views.add(getChildAt(i));
    }
  }

  public void hideViewAtIndex(int index) {
    if (index >= 0 && index < views.size()) {
      views.get(index).setVisibility(GONE);
      arrangeElements();
    }
  }

  public void showViewAtIndex(int index) {
    if (index >= 0 && index < views.size()) {
      views.get(index).setVisibility(VISIBLE);
      arrangeElements();
    }
  }
}
```

Here is how to use it:

Save all the children of the GridLayout after it is bound (rendered), use the following code

```
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    RearrangingGridLayout rglPrices = findViewById(R.id.rglPrices);

    rglPrices.saveViews();
  }
```

Now, to hide your view

```
rglPrices.hideViewAtIndex(indexOfView);
```

Similarly, to show your view

```
rglPrices.showViewAtIndex(indexOfView);
```

And you are done!

For my project, it was essential to preserve the children's position so I went with index. You can easily modify the code to work with something else like view id, by updating the show and hide functions.

Comment: You can also directly implement and use it: https://github.com/u-barnwal/RearrangingGridLayout

Answer (score 0):

this is excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65402196/8084692)

for those who want to pass view instead of index into functions.

```
public void hideView(View child) {
    for (int i = 0; i < views.size(); i++) {
        if (views.get(i).getId() == child.getId()) {
            views.get(i).setVisibility(GONE);
            arrangeElements();
            break;
        }
    }
}

public void showView(View child) {
    for (int i = 0; i < views.size(); i++) {
        if (views.get(i).getId() == child.getId()) {
            views.get(i).setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            arrangeElements();
        }
    }
}
```